# Eclipse with m2e plugin solves dependencies itself?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I checkout my Maven project into Eclipse via Import / Checkout Maven Projects from SCM and now I see that in Maven dependencies there are libraries that are not yet mentioned (e.g. javax) in my pom.xml file (see a picture). And source code that uses these dependency libraries doesn't report any dependency problem.

What does it mean to Eclipse and what does it mean for me for manually defining dependencies in pom.xml file?

[image: Eclipse project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a transitive dependency for your project. Open the POM in eclipse and in the bottom look in the Dependency Hierarchy tab.